# Mesclar um Objeto com um Array de Objetos Javascript ES6!

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Pessoal tenho as seguintes variáveis!

```
let content = {
  cd_empresa: 200,
  cd_produto: 13287,
  cd_status: 604,
  dt_validade: '2019-05-09T12:34:00',
  dv_possui_subvencao: 1,
  dv_regra: 1,
  fl_possui_item: 1,
  id_parceiro_portal: 0,
  id_proposta: 10003,
  id_proposta_itens: null,
  nm_fase: 'Nova Cotação',
  nm_origem: 'Liderança',
  nm_pessoa_cliente: 'André Flores Vivas',
  nm_produto: 'AGRÍCOLA',
  nm_ramo: '1-AGRÍCOLA',
  nm_status: 'Recusada',
  nr_fase: 4,
  nr_grp_produto: null,
  produto_vip: 0
};

let headers = [
  { text: 'Nr° Cotação', value: 'id_proposta' },
  { text: 'Origem', value: 'nm_origem' },
  { text: 'Status', value: 'nm_status' },
  { text: 'Fase', value: 'nm_fase' }
];
```

Preciso transformar o gerar uma nova variável que mescle essas informações onde só vai permanecer os que existem no `headers.value` mais pegando o valor do mesmo da `let content` segue um exemplo de como preciso:

```
let result = {
  'Nr° Cotação': 10003,
  Origem: 'Liderança',
  Status: 'Recusada',
  Fase: 'Nova Cotação'
};
```

ou:

```
let result = [{ 'Nr° Cotação': 10003 }, { Origem: 'Liderança' }, { Status: 'Recusada' }, { Fase: 'Nova Cotação' }];
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `reduce` para mapear as propriedades:

```js
const converter = (origem, mapa) => {
  return mapa.reduce((acumulador, { text, value }) => {
    return {
      ...acumulador,
      [text]: origem[value],
    };
  }, {});
};

const converter2 = (origem, mapa) => {
  return mapa.reduce((acumulador, { text, value }) => {
    return [
      ...acumulador,
      { [text]: origem[value] },
    ];
  }, []);
};

// Execução

let content = {
  cd_empresa: 200,
  cd_produto: 13287,
  cd_status: 604,
  dt_validade: '2019-05-09T12:34:00',
  dv_possui_subvencao: 1,
  dv_regra: 1,
  fl_possui_item: 1,
  id_parceiro_portal: 0,
  id_proposta: 10003,
  id_proposta_itens: null,
  nm_fase: 'Nova Cotação',
  nm_origem: 'Liderança',
  nm_pessoa_cliente: 'André Flores Vivas',
  nm_produto: 'AGRÍCOLA',
  nm_ramo: '1-AGRÍCOLA',
  nm_status: 'Recusada',
  nr_fase: 4,
  nr_grp_produto: null,
  produto_vip: 0
};

let headers = [
  { text: 'Nr° Cotação', value: 'id_proposta' },
  { text: 'Origem', value: 'nm_origem' },
  { text: 'Status', value: 'nm_status' },
  { text: 'Fase', value: 'nm_fase' }
];

console.log(converter(content, headers));
console.log(converter2(content, headers));
```

---

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```

Comment: Opa vlw, show em brother! consegui aplicar aqui.. muito bom msm!
tava quebrando a cuca pra resolver isso!
consigo também deixar no segundo formato do exemplo?

`let result = [{ 'Nr° Cotação': 10003 }, { Origem: 'Liderança' }, { Status: 'Recusada' }, { Fase: 'Nova Cotação' }];` Obrigado!

Comment: Muito bom amigo, isso já é novidade do ES6 correto ?

Comment: @PhilipRamkeerat não, o reduce vem de versões anteriores do ECMAScript

Comment: @wDrik sim, você pode alterar a função do `reduce` retornar um `array`

Comment: @Sorack Entendi porem não consegui aplicar.. se coloco o retorno no formato Array.. ele vai identando cada item dentro de um sub item Array.. consigo realmente fazer isso manipulando o reduce? ou preciso tratar isso a parte? Obrigado!

Comment: @wDrik adicionei uma função para o segundo exemplo de resultado

Comment: @Sorack Valeu man.. entendi tava colocando os colchetes antes do `...obj`, Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 3):

É preferível utilizar reduce, como na resposta aceita. Mas se você prefere um método mais imperativo:

```js
let content = {
  cd_empresa: 200,
  cd_produto: 13287,
  cd_status: 604,
  dt_validade: '2019-05-09T12:34:00',
  dv_possui_subvencao: 1,
  dv_regra: 1,
  fl_possui_item: 1,
  id_parceiro_portal: 0,
  id_proposta: 10003,
  id_proposta_itens: null,
  nm_fase: 'Nova Cotação',
  nm_origem: 'Liderança',
  nm_pessoa_cliente: 'André Flores Vivas',
  nm_produto: 'AGRÍCOLA',
  nm_ramo: '1-AGRÍCOLA',
  nm_status: 'Recusada',
  nr_fase: 4,
  nr_grp_produto: null,
  produto_vip: 0
};

let headers = [
  { text: 'Nr° Cotação', value: 'id_proposta' },
  { text: 'Origem', value: 'nm_origem' },
  { text: 'Status', value: 'nm_status' },
  { text: 'Fase', value: 'nm_fase' }
];

function populate(headers, content) {
  const result = {}

  headers.forEach(item => {
    const { text, value} = item
    const contentKey = content[value]
    
    result[text] = contentKey
  })
  
  return result
}

console.log(populate(headers, content))
```

Comment: Opa, legal man um alternativa para resolver a questão.. porem optei em utilizar o reduce.. consegui diminuir bastante o numero de linhas em relação a essa alternativa! Obrigado!